# High school experiments recommendations

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, home-experiment

I am from India and you know teachers don't show the experiments and they only give the theory but I want to see experiments video at least so I'm satisfied that physics is correct , can you tell me some websites / channels which show high school experiments .

Comment: Can you specify your area of interest? Mechanics, E&M, Circuits, Optics?

Comment: If you don't get good answers here, you might ask in [chat] either (a) about some actual recommendations or (b) about workshopping this question into a more inviting form. This is a little different from most of our [tag:resource-recommendations] questions, but I'm willing to let the community decide whether it works for us or not.

Comment: Swag , ( I love EM and nuclear physics )

Answer (score 1):

Well I think as you are asking for High school course, I believe that you should prefer YT videos by Walter Lewin [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCiEHVhv0SBMpP75JbzJShqw&ved=2ahUKEwj4j_Ob4rzvAhUu4zgGHdHKCW4QFjAAegQIAxAH&usg=AOvVaw09SeYA_wzqGTJhlVHpa8Ry).

He was a professor at MIT and has an unique way of teaching the subject with the demonstrations wherever it is required. The videos cover Newtonian Mechanics, Electromagnetism, Vibrations and Waves,Bohr's model and a brief Introduction to Quantum Mechanics. Along with this he has quiz questions as well and he demonstrates them in his own way.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to do some basic experiments on your own. Like when I was a High school student, I really did some easy experiments that teach me a lot! It's true you can not do those experiment which needs expensive apparatus but still, you can do a basic experiment and learn a lot.

---

My favorite is A Simple Pendulum! We all know the physics behind the time period,
$$T=2\pi \sqrt\frac{l}{g}$$
Now it's time to test it! Try making your own pendulum, Measure the length of the string and take your stopwatch and record the time for several periods and see if You can figure out $g$.

---

I bought a multimeter so that I can do experiment with electromagnetics origin. Most of them were based on Faraday's law. Like producing the current in the coil by moving the magnet. And many others and it's fun!

I remember I take a small motor which is got from some electronic instrument, take a mobile charger lead make connected it. I take a fan sort of thing which I have fitted to the moving part of the motor, then put the fan facing the a cooler. I take the reading from the multimeter for How much the voltage motor is creating and found it was around  5 to 6 Volt and then I connected my mobile, and It starts charging. Note that It was a button mobile, not an android they take much more power.

There many things you can try!

---

**On resources**

You need to be specific here. I think googling the experiment if it's famous will give you hundreds of sites and videos that you can see. But You can watch a free course like the one given by [NPTEL](https://nptel.ac.in/course.html). Look for the course on Experimental physics like [this one](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/115/105/115105120/).